# How to connect instance directly to ext-net(external network)?

Tags: openstack

Im using openstack neutron with 3 nodes and all are working perfectly using virtual router that is connected to ext-net and internal interface,I would like to asks if its possible that the instance is directly connected to ext-net without virtual router and internal interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Connecting via the router is the way it should work: 
https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/3086/directly-connect-vm-to-external-network/